# Encoding of string returned from 'system' command

Tags: regex, linux, string, matlab, character-encoding

I am trying to read some meta-date returned from ffmpeg on a Linux machine. I am doing it from Matlab using the `system` command. My call to regexp fails to find what I am looking for (it works ok on Windows). The line I am parsing looks like this:

> Duration: 06:33:42.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 65 kb/s

and I am parsing the duration with a call like this:

> dur = regexp(w, 'Duration: [[0-9]+:]+.[0-9]+','match');

where `w` holds the string returned from the call to ffmpeg. The result is that `dur` is empty, meaning regexp failed to match the query. If I save `w` and load it on a Windows machine, I see this (I truncated the line but you can get the idea):

> [0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m  Duration: [0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m06:33:42.17[0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m[0m[0;39m

which made me suspect some encoding issues.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is your exact call to the `system` command?  How are you getting the output into `w`?

Comment: `[s, w] = system([ffmpeg ' -i ' fnm]);`, where `ffmpeg` holds full path to the executable, and `fnm` is the input audio file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look like terminal control codes; ANSI color codes to be more specific. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors ) You may need to look into passing a flag or something to suppress those, if ffmpeg has such an option. (Usually, programs will auto-detect if stdout is an interactive terminal and figure out this on their own)

Comment: Great. ffmpeg does have this option, by setting an environment variable called AV_LOG_FORCE_NOCOLOR (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options), which solved the problem. Thanks!